# How to align text under a row of floating divs

Tags: html, css, alignment

I am a beginner web design student. I am trying to code the following image. [image: see the snapshot of the image I am trying to code] 
But this is what is happening instead [see this screenshot of my work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnQmN.png)

I created parent divs that contain the three boxes (each their own child div) and the text, and floated them. Now how do I get the text to stay under the boxes, at the bottom of the parent div? I tried absolute position but it didn't work. Does anyone have any ideas for me? 
Here is my HTML:

```
    <div>
            <div class="box" id="standard">
                <i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <p>Standard</p>
            </div>
            <p>Triggered by a contact's time of enrollment, like joining a smart list or filling out a form.</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="box">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <p>Fixed Date</p>
            </div>
            <p>Triggered by a calendar date, like a webinar, conference, or holiday.</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="box">   
                <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <p>Property Based</p>
            </div>
            <p>Triggered by a contact date property, like a trial expiration date or renewal date.</p>
        </div>
```

And my CSS:

```
     .box {
     height: 184px;
     width: 187px;
     border: 1px solid #00a4bd;
     moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
     text-align: center;
     line-height: 80px;
     margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
     font-size: 18px;
     float: left;
     }

     #standard {
     border: 2px solid #00a4bd;
     background-color: #e5f5f8;
     }
```

I would be so grateful for any advice!
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please put a [mcve] in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```css
#box{width:200px;
height:200px;
border:1px solid #454545;}
#description{position:relative;
 top:100%;}
```

```html
<div id="box">

<div id="description">descripttion of the box </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at your code, one way to obtain the result you want is to do the following.

1. Create three DIV's which include the text per image. Create these DIV's under the DIV's which include the images.
2. Give the first DIV which includes your text a class with the CSS property "clear: both;" This will tell this DIV to stop floating to the left (or wrap around other floating elements) and follow the normal elementflow.

As a result, the text should be below the images provided the DIV's with the text have the same width property as the DIV's with the images. Please find below an example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
    float: left;
    border: red solid 1px; 
    width: 20%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div> 
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/63/Noto_Project_Christmas_Tree_Emoji.svg/2000px-Noto_Project_Christmas_Tree_Emoji.svg.png">  
    </div>
    <div> 
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/63/Noto_Project_Christmas_Tree_Emoji.svg/2000px-Noto_Project_Christmas_Tree_Emoji.svg.png">  
    </div>
    <div> 
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/63/Noto_Project_Christmas_Tree_Emoji.svg/2000px-Noto_Project_Christmas_Tree_Emoji.svg.png">  
    </div>

<div class="clear">My christmas tree </div>
<div>My christmas tree </div>
<div>My christmas tree </div>


</body>
</html>
```

See it in action: https://jsfiddle.net/gbq0xf8b/

Note: read more about a so-called "clearfix" at http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/ . This is a more elaborate way of clearing the first DIV and returning to the normal elementflow. This method is commonly used in practice (or so I heard..I'm a beginner).